# CSS3 animation transform rotate with no visible transition

Tags: css, animation

So, I have an image:

[image]

I'd like to rotate it on hover, to give the illusion of the squares animating different colours. However, I had to settle for:

```
.logo:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

As if I used `animation` and keyframes with % step, you could physically see the logo rotate, I'd like it to snap to the next `deg` value, if possible. How could I do this infinitely on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the timing-functions [steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_steps%28%29_class_of_timing-functions),

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.logo:hover {
    -webkit-animation: rotate 1s infinite steps(2, start);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3M2C/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function